# Is it possible to share the image located in drawable folder on social platform in viewpager ? (One user says he is not sure, How about you )

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, share

I have created viewpager app that is suppose to display images located in the drawable folder. I read android official guide and changed my code ,but it is not working for me. Any help will be appreciated....The user should be able to share the image located in drawable folder ..they like on various platforms according to the app downloaded in their phones.. My question is it possible ?. If yes, please..please.. provide some code..

Following are my codes...

Mainactivity.java

```
  import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;




    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        MediaPlayer oursong;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
          oursong.start ();
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
      }

      private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;


      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate menu resource file.
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

          // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
          MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

          // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
          mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

          // Return true to display menu
          return true;
      }

      // Call to update the share intent
      private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
          if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
              mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
          }
      }

         @Override
         protected void onPause(){
         super.onPause();
          oursong.release();
     }

    }
```

imageadapter.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private final int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three
    };
    ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_small);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
      imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);

      imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View view) {

                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager  = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                    try {
                            myWallpaperManager.setResource(GalImages[position]);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                             e.printStackTrace();
                    }       

           }

           });


      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
```

I am new to android programming so..please provide some explanation along with the code..if possible..thanks..

Answer (score 0):

> The user should be able to share the image they like on various
>   platforms according to the app downloaded in their phones

Yes, of course it is possible.

You have to use `Intent`s to do that. I am not sure if one can send the images from the drawable folder, never tried that. However, if you want to let people share the images from the gallery or something:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");

Uri uri = Uri.parse(pathToImage);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent),"Share Via...")
```

What this is doing is that it is representing the *intention* of your application that it wants to send an image.

Comment: ...I am not sure.. but by "Gallery" you meant the image that are stored on phone.. right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Images on the phone. :)